# How to change directory to catkin workspace, then catkin_make, then go back

Tags: linux

Currently, I use the following alias to do that:

```
alias ck='export ck_dir=`pwd` && cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make && cd $ck_dir'
```

This only works if catkin_make finish without error. Is there any modification so that

```
cd $ck_dir
```

works even if catkin_make failed?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't solve your question, but here's a hint to simplify: Use `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd` commands and you won't have to use the `ck_dir` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your && with a semi-colon (;).

Here are some tips to remember:

```
&& = continue only if previous command passed  
|| = continue only if previous command failed
; = continue regardless of whether the previous command passed or failed
```